# 8 queens unknown error in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This function isn't terminating! I'm trying to generate all possible safe combinations on an eight by eight chessboard for eight queens. I'm not sure what's going wrong. My code is below. The board is represented as [x1, x2...x8] where the value xi is the column, and the index of said value is the row.

the safeH function should create all the combinations of eight numbers without duplications for example [1,4,3,5,8,6,7,2],[6,4,8,2,5,1,3,7] and so on...

the safeD function will compare the first element with all successors elements to ensure that there is no queen placed on the diagonal of this queen(this element) and so on ..

```
queens = [ [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] | x1 <- [1..8], x2 <- [1..8]
                                     , x3 <- [1..8], x4 <- [1..8]
                                     , x5 <- [1..8], x6 <- [1..8]
                                     , x7 <- [1..8], x8 <- [1..8]
                                     , safeH [x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] x1
                                     , safeD [x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] x1
                                             [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] 1 ]

safeH l e =
  if elem e l then False
  else if length (l)/=0 then safeH(tail l)(head l)
       else True

safeD l e xs n =
  if last xs /= e then
    if length l /= 0 then
      if head l + n == e || head l - n == e then False
      else safeD (tail l) e xs (n + 1)
    else safeD (tail xs) (head xs) xs 1
  else True
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  How is it supposed to do it?  What do you expect it to do?  What is it actually doing?

Comment: the safeH function will create all the combinations of the eight numbers without duplication for example [1,4,3,5,8,6,7,2],[6,4,8,2,5,1,3,7] and so on...

Comment: Also, how much faster and cleaner would it be if you just generated all permutations of the list [1..8]? (Hint: a lot.) Obviously, 2 numbers can't be the same because then the queens would be in the same row. `import Data.List; permutations [1..8]`

Comment: @Mhd I asked those questions to point out that answers to them should be added to the question.  Rather than replying in the comments, please clarify these topics in the question.

Comment: the safeH function will create all the combinations of eight numbers without duplication for example [1,4,3,5,8,6,7,2],[6,4,8,2,5,1,3,7] and so on... each number will express a line one of the queens will place on ,then the safeD function will compare the first element with all successors elements to ensure that there is no queen placed on the diagonal of this queen(this element) and so on ..we will check this function for all elements ... @JoshuaTaylor

Comment: @Mhd As I said, please add the clarification _to the question_.  You can edit your question, instead of adding a comment.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor they did edit the question, and 9 minutes later it got closed on them. >:-< Whaddaya know, it is *sooo* easy to close a question these days. And then another guy comes along and wants to answer; and can't. Ain't it great. All this excessive lawyering is not tiresome at all. Shouldn't it be the *responsibility* of those who voted to close, to inspect the *edited* question and re-vote to re-open? Isn't this question *appears* to be exactly "on-topic", now? i.e. its "specific problem" is the "reproducible" (I assume) non-termination of valid (seemingly) code. Isn't it?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor never mind.

Answer (score 4):

As per the comments on Simon's answer, rather than fix your code, I'll step through my own. I hope it's useful for you to get a better understanding of the problem and understand Haskell a little better. Obviously, if this is for an assignment, you shouldn't submit my code.

Fair warning -- I'm very new to Haskell too, so I'm open to any suggestions from the peanut gallery!

```
import Data.List
{- myNQueens n will solve the n-queens problem for the given board-size nxn 
   for n queens. Each board is represented by [x1, x2..xn] where the index
   represents the column and the value of xi represents the row. -} 

--type: this function takes an Int and returns a list of lists of Ints.
myNQueens :: Int -> [[Int]]
-- here is a list comprehension that does away with your safeH function.
-- it checks all permutations of the numbers [1..n] to see if they represent
-- a legal board. As you'll see, queensSafe only checks diagonals. Horizontals
-- do not need to be checked because generating the permutations already takes
-- care of that. If you'd prefer not to use Data.List.permutations, it shouldn't
-- be too hard to hand-roll your own.
myNQueens n = [x | x <- permutations [1..n], queensSafe x]

--type: from list of Ints to bool. Returns True if legal board, else False.
queensSafe :: [Int] -> Bool
-- queensSafe is a recursive function that checks if the queen in the first column
-- can be captured. If so, it returns false. If not, it is called again with the board
-- without the first column.

-- base case: the empty board is safe
queensSafe [] = True
-- l@(x:xs) is just pattern matching. x is the first element of the
-- list, xs is the remaining elements, and l is just syntactic sugar for
-- referencing the whole list.
queensSafe l@(x:xs)
-- these "guards" are basically if-else statements.
-- if firstQueenSafe l == True then queensSafe x:xs = queensSafe xs. else, False.
    | firstQueenSafe l == True = queensSafe xs
    | otherwise = False



firstQueenSafe :: [Int] -> Bool
firstQueenSafe l@(x:xs) =
    -- unsafe1 generates a list of all of the unsafe diagonals down and to the right.
    -- unsafe2 generates a list of all of the unsafe diagonals up and to the left.
    let unsafe1 = [x, x - 1 .. x - length l]
        unsafe2 = [x, x + 1 .. x + length l]
        -- zipped just pairs unsafe1 and unsafe2 with copies of the actual board 
        -- (except the first element.) If any of tuples contain 2 of the same values,
        -- then the board is unsafe.
        zipped = zip (tail unsafe1) (tail l) ++ zip (tail unsafe2) (tail l)
        -- countMatches just checks if there are any matches in zipped.
        countMatches = length [x | x <- zipped, fst x == snd x]
    in if countMatches == 0 then True else False
```

Obviously, this is non-optimal, but I think it's pretty clear. And quite a short piece of code! Just to show that it works:

```
*Main> head $ myNQueens 8
[6,4,7,1,3,5,2,8]
*Main> head $ myNQueens 9
[6,3,5,8,1,4,2,7,9]
*Main> head $ myNQueens 10
[7,5,8,2,9,3,6,4,1,10]
*Main> length $ myNQueens 8 -- runs in about a second
92
*Main> length $ myNQueens 9 -- runs in about 20 seconds
352
*Main> length $ myNQueens 10 -- runs in a couple of minutes
724
```

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org) are both really good resources. I'm also working through [99 Haskell Problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99%3a_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems), which is where I originally saw this problem. If you'd like to see some simple code that solves some of these other problems, (I'm not really trying to optimize, just make easy and readable code so I can learn) you can fork https://github.com/ostrowr/99-Haskell-Problems

Comment: thanks a lot and do not worry i will not submit your code in any place :)

Comment: `queensSafe l@(x:xs) | firstQueenSafe l == True = queensSafe xs | otherwise = False` is nicer written as `queensSafe qs@(_:t) = firstQueenSafe qs && queensSafe t`. :)

Comment: @WillNess thanks! I really didn't like my equality comparison to `True` or binding to `x` without using it. I'll edit once I get back on my computer and have a chance to test the new code.

Comment: peanut gallery says you shouldn't use permutations. Consider that queen 2 is at the wrong position with respect to queen 1. permutations will still generate all permutations of other queens for this position of queen 1 and 2, which will never result in a solution. When you start from a solution for zero queens, you may spot the inductive pattern, and the solution for 10 queens will take less than one second.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compute `queens`, one must iterate through 8^8 = 16777216 cases, each of which will be subject to `safeH` and `safeD`. This would take quite a while.

```
queens = [ [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] | x1 <- [1..8], x2 <- [1..8]
                                     , x3 <- [1..8], x4 <- [1..8]
                                     , x5 <- [1..8], x6 <- [1..8]
                                     , x7 <- [1..8], x8 <- [1..8]
```

You could look into how others have solved [the 8-queens problem in Haskell](http://en.literateprograms.org/Eight_Queens_puzzle_%28Haskell%29).

Comment: While this is true, it won't solve his code's other problems.

Comment: yes that is right but i think eventually the code will give us the answer right? or there are other as @rogaos said??

Comment: @Mhd sadly enough, I'm pretty sure it won't ever give you the right answer. Your safeD function is wrong. Honestly I'm struggling to what you're trying to do with this code. I've written up my own solution which I'm happy to step through in an answer if you think it would be helpful, but I'm not comfortable fixing your code as is.

Comment: thanks for your effort and please it will be very helpful if you put your answer :) @rogaos

Comment: @Mhd I can't now because your question has been closed. If you post a clearer one (or get this reopened? not sure of the protocol) I'm happy to help.

Comment: @rogaos the question has been re-opened, you can post your answer now. :)