# Exception: Prelude.last: empty list in Haskell solving 8-queens?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, n-queens

I'm solving the 8-queens problem in Haskell using only basic functions nothing fancy
this is the code:

```
queens = [[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]|x1<-[1..8],x2<-[1..8],x3<-[1..8],x4<-[1..8],x5<-[1..8],x6<-[1..8],x7<-[1..8],x8<-[1..8],safeH [x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] x1,safeD [x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] x1 [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] 1] 
safeH l e = if elem e l then False 
            else if length (l)/=0 then safeH(tail l)(head l) 
                    else True
safeD l e xs n = if last(xs)/=e || length xs == 0 then
                if length(l)/=0 then 
                    if (head(l)+n==e || head(l)-n==e) then False 
                    else safeD(tail l)(e)(xs)(n+1) 
                else safeD(tail xs)(head xs)(tail xs)(1)
            else True
```

To clarify the `SafeH` function checks that no queens are in the same row H stands for Horizantly while the `SafeD` is supposed to check for diagonal conflicts
I am sure that the `SafeH` function is okay the problem with `SafeD`
and when compiling the code it gives me no problems but when calling the `queens` function
it gives me this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( y.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> queens
*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
```

can anyone please help me?? thanks in advance for every thing :)

Comment: Are you related to MHD? Maybe taking the same course? This looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342109/8-queens-unknown-error-in-haskell.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner yes sir we are a team trying to solve this problem but he didn't know who to ask this question ??

Answer (score 5):

You can fix the immediate problem by checking the length of `xs` before calling `last`:

```
safeD l e xs n = if length xs == 0 || last(xs)/=e then ...
```

However, you will then run into another problem because you call `safeD(tail xs)(head xs)(tail xs)(1)` inside the `then` part of this branch, and you can reach the `then` part of this branch when `length xs == 0`.

I strongly recommend learning a little bit about pattern matching ([Gentle Intro section](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html), [Haskell Report section](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17)) and trying to write this entire code snippet without ever calling `head`, `tail`, `init`, `last`, or `length`. Instead, use the two patterns `[]` for matching empty lists and `(x:xs)` (or similar) for matching lists that start as `x` and end with `xs`; if necessary, a call to `reverse` once in a while would be okay.

Good luck, and let us know how you fare and where you get stuck!

Answer (score 3):

Ever thought of solving this problem for zero queens first?

Then for one queen?

Then spot the inductive / recursive pattern?.. I am not quoting the 3-liner solution, as it looks like your homework.